# encode and decode - Hebrew string look like gibberish - Python 3 from Teradata

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I connected to my Teradata DB and extract simple query result to a dataframe.
The dataframe (df_clients) has 1 column (FirstName) and 1 row with Hebrew string ('שלום לך')
as I print the dataframe I get gibberish instead of Hebrew language:
ùìåí ìê

I find a solution to encode and decode string:

```
strr = "ùìåí ìê"

print( strr) #not good

print( strr.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255',errors='replace')) #good
```

it worked.. but when I tried the same solution with Pandas Dataframe it doesn't work (no error, but don't work):

```
df_clients.FirstName.apply(lambda x : x.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255',errors='replace') )
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of your string encoding in Pandas is `.str.<de|encode>`. I have generated example of the same number as demo:

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':["ùìåí ìê", "ùìåí ìê"]
})

dataf["name"].str.encode('cp1252').str.decode('cp1255',errors='replace')

# result
# 0    שלום לך
# 1    שלום לך
```

#### Update

> [assign and] a solution that can handle all rows[|columns].

```py
import pandas as pd

dataf = pd.DataFrame({
    'first_name':["ùìåí ìê", "ùìåí ìê"], 'last_name': ["ùìåí ìê", "ùìåí ìê"]
})

# all columns [assuming all are text]

dataf = dataf.transform(lambda x: x.str.encode('cp1252', ,errors='replace').str.decode('cp1255', errors='replace'))

# or selecting subset of columns

dataf[["first_name","last_name"]] = dataf[["first_name","last_name"]].transform(lambda x: x.str.encode('cp1252', errors='replace' ).str.decode('cp1255',errors='replace'))

dataf

#    first_name last_name
# 0 שלום לך שלום לך
# 1 שלום לך שלום לך
```

If there are errors, try set `errors='ignore'` and see what worked and which characters are still gibberish.

Comment: my friend, can you show me how to change the dataframe column values? because printing work, but changing values in dataframe not working.. and a solution that can handle all rows... not just 1 row (like i did with the lambda). think i have 50 columns and 1M rows

Comment: i did it and got an error:  <UnicodeEncodeError>
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>

this is what i wrote:

Comment: In the encode do the replace error too as in decode `encode('cp1252', errors='replace')`

Comment: same error...
df_clients["FirstName"] = df_clients["FirstName"].transform(lambda x : x.str.encode('cp1252', errors='replace').str.decode('cp1255',errors='replace') )

Comment: can't work it out? you seem like a smart guy , i will be very happy if you could help me  :) thank you so much for trying so far

Comment: Set error to `errors='ignore'` but check the results as it will ignore places it fails